# Safari Browser: Switch to frame is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browserstack, safaridriver

I am trying to run few test on Mobile Emulators (Safari Browser) and stuck at a problem. Where after switching to an Iframe I am not able to do any action.

There is already a closed issue for that, however I didn't find any solution after going though this thread.

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5832

Code which is causing issue

```
 public PaymentPage fillCreditCardInformation(String cardNumber, String expiryDate, String cvv, String postal ){
        switchToPaymentFrame();
        WebElement cardNumberEditbox = driver.findElement(By.name("cardnumber"));
}

private void switchToPaymentFrame() {
    WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.name("__privateStripeFrame3"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
}
```

Emulator Used: Iphone 6s, IPad Mini 
Webdriver Version: 3.4.0 
Safari Driver: 2.48

**Stacktrace:**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: undefined is not an object 
>   (evaluating 'a.querySelectorAll') (WARNING: The server did not provide
>   any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 30.48 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'DL0019', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-96-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{noReset=true, safari=true,
>   browserstack.tunnelIdentifier=, browserstack.asyncStop=true,
>   language=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131),
>   browserstack.selenium_version=3.4.0, deviceName==iPad Retina (9.1)
>   [556DF534-C4AE-48B6-8ED3-BAF86198074A], platform=MAC,
>   browserstack.video.disableWaterMark=true, desired={noReset=true,
>   browserstack.tunnelIdentifier=, browserstack.asyncStop=true,
>   language=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131),
>   browserstack.selenium_version=3.4.0, deviceName==iPad Retina (9.1)
>   [556DF534-C4AE-48B6-8ED3-BAF86198074A], platform=MAC,
>   browserstack.video.disableWaterMark=true, acceptSslCerts=false,
>   newCommandTimeout=300.0, browser=ipad, platformVersion=9.1,
>   acceptSslCert=false, browserName=safari, platformName=iOS,
>   64bit=false, browserstack.debug=true, orientation=portrait,
>   browserstack.ie.noFlash=false, os_version=,
>   mobile={"browser":"tablet","version":"iPad Mini 4-9.1"},
>   browserstack.geckodriver=0.16.0, version=, browserstack.video=true,
>   safariIgnoreFraudWarning=true, orig_os=macelc, realMobile=false,
>   deviceOrientation=PORTRAIT, device=iPad Retina, proxy_type=node},
>   acceptSslCerts=false, newCommandTimeout=300.0, browser=ipad,
>   platformVersion=9.1, webStorageEnabled=false, acceptSslCert=false,
>   browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   platformName=iOS, 64bit=false, browserstack.debug=true,
>   networkConnectionEnabled=false, orientation=portrait,
>   browserstack.ie.noFlash=false, warnings={}, os_version=,
>   mobile={"browser":"tablet","version":"iPad Mini 4-9.1"},
>   browserstack.geckodriver=0.16.0, databaseEnabled=false, version=,
>   browserstack.video=true, safariIgnoreFraudWarning=true,
>   orig_os=macelc, realMobile=false, locationContextEnabled=false,
>   deviceOrientation=PORTRAIT, device=iPad Retina, proxy_type=node}]
>   Session ID: 6bf643515813d0ccbe5fe75300ac2d8ea15a5960
>   *** Element info: {Using=name, value=cardnumber}

Comment: You mentioned `Webdriver Version: 3.5.2` but in logs `Build info: version: '2.52.0'` Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks, I just realized that. Changing the version in config doesn't have effect on browserstack. (atleast for safari)

Comment: That should't be the case. Atleast for Web Emulators `browserstack` did that happily when we used `DesiredCapabilities`

Comment: @DebanjanB got it. my local pom was having version`2.52.0` and so stacktrace was showing 2.52.0. I updated local version as well and so no stacktrace reflects the correct version. But still stuck at problem.

Comment: I think I can smell the issue now. Can you show me the code block?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added the code.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I am running into this now..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

Change:

```
private void switchToPaymentFrame() {
    WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.name("__privateStripeFrame3"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
}
```

To:

```
private void switchToPaymentFrame() {
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("__privateStripeFrame3")));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as if frame is not found it will throw an error saying elementnofound. However, I tried and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like a known issue. 
Simply doesn't work.

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7658